# Inserting Values from a Textbox into Database

Tags: javascript, ios, sqlite, react-native, expo

**I am fairly new to React Native, and yes, there are questions with a similar title but my question's context is different.**

I am using React Native, using JavaScript, to create an app on my IOS device. I have text input in my code, and when a submit button is pressed, whatever text was in the text input goes to another screen, which I have done using `navigate`.  I would like to still do this, but also have a database that will store this information, possibly using SQLite. I have found no information on how to have a database to connect to the text input as well as making a database for this text input.

If anyone can help me with the starting process of building a database and connecting it to text input, that would be a huge help! Let me know if you need to see some of the code I currently have. I appreciate any help!

Comment: show what you tried

Comment: @YaShChaudhary How can I try if I don't know how to get started?

Comment: use fetch to send receive or save the data https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html